# After host change jQuery not working.old server code running perfectly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-4

I changed my web hosting server recently.  After that, I realized that some parts of my jQuery code are not working. Dropdown menu not change. I checked that the old server code still now working perfectly but not on my live server.

My old server link:http://pixcelcoder.in/care-foundation/auth-admin-panel/admin-dashboard/care-class-main-chapter-list.php

New sever link:https://careonlineschool.org/care-foundation/auth-admin-panel/admin-dashboard/care-class-main-chapter-list

```
<?php include('header.php')?>
<!-- Main Content -->
<div class="hk-pg-wrapper">
<!-- Container -->
<div class="container mt-xl-50 mt-sm-30 mt-15">
    <!-- Title -->
    <div class="hk-pg-header align-items-top">
       
        <!-- /Title -->
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
            Add Main Chapter
            </button>
            
        <!-- Table Contain -->
        <div class="container">
          <br><br>
          <h2>Main Chapter List </h2>
          <hr>
          <table class="table table-striped table-responsive w-100 d-block d-md-table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Class</th>
                <th>Subject Name</th>
                <th>Main Chapter</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                    $notice_query="select * FROM care_class_main_chapter";
                    $notice_result = mysqli_query($con,$notice_query);
                     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notice_result))
                
                 {
                 ?>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    $class_name_query="select * FROM care_class INNER JOIN care_class_main_chapter ON care_class.care_class_id=care_class_main_chapter.care_class_id  WHERE care_class_main_chapter.care_class_id = $row[care_class_id]";
                    $class_name_result = mysqli_query($con,$class_name_query);
                    $class_name_row=mysqli_fetch_array($class_name_result);
                    echo $class_name_row['care_class_number'];
                    ?>
                </td> 
                <td>
                <?php
                 $subject_name_query="select * FROM care_subject INNER JOIN care_class_main_chapter ON care_subject.care_subject_id=care_class_main_chapter.care_subject_id  WHERE care_class_main_chapter.care_subject_id = $row[care_subject_id]";
                 $subject_name_result = mysqli_query($con,$subject_name_query);
                 $subject_name_row=mysqli_fetch_array($subject_name_result);
                 echo $subject_name_row['care_subject_name'];
                ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $row['care_class_main_chapter_name']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="care-class-main-chapter-list-edit.php?care_class_main_chapter_id=<?php echo $row["care_class_main_chapter_id"]; ?>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="care-class-main-chapter-list-delete.php?care_class_main_chapter_id=<?php echo $row["care_class_main_chapter_id"]; ?>">Delete</a></td>
              </tr>
              <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <!-- End Table Contain -->

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Main Chapter</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-group" action="" method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                             <!-- Section for Include Class -->
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <label for="Text">Class</label>
                                  <select name="care_class_id" id="care_class_id" required>
                                    <option value="">Select Class</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                            <!-- End Section for Include class -->
                             
                            <!-- Section for Include Subject -->
                            <div class="col-6">
                                <label for="Text">Subject</label>
                                  <select name="care_subject_id" id="care_subject_id"required>
                                    <option value="">Select Subject</option>
                                  </select>
                            </div>
                             <!-- End Section for Include Subject -->
                        </div>
                              <br>
                        <label for="class">Main Chapter</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Subject" name="care_class_main_chapter_name" required>
              </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="main-chapter-add-button">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                                <?php
                                if(isset($_POST['main-chapter-add-button']))
                                {
                                    $care_class_id=$_POST['care_class_id'];
                                    $care_subject_id=$_POST['care_subject_id'];
                                    $care_class_main_chapter_name=$_POST['care_class_main_chapter_name'];
                                    
                                    $query="INSERT INTO `care_class_main_chapter` (`care_class_id`,`care_subject_id`,`care_class_main_chapter_name`) VALUES ('$care_class_id','$care_subject_id','$care_class_main_chapter_name')";
                                  if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
                                   {
                                        echo '<script>swal("Main Chapter Added Sucessfully", "Please proceed", "success").then((value) => {
                                                    window.location.href="care-class-main-chapter-list.php"; });
                                                    </script>';
                                   }
                                   else
                                   {
                                      echo '<script>swal("Something Wrong", "Please proceed", "error").then((value) => {
                                                    window.location.href="care-class-main-chapter-list.php"; });
                                                    </script>';
                                   }
                                }
                               ?>
                            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        function loadData(type,subject_id){
                            $.ajax({
                              url : "care-class-main-chapter-list-ajax.php",
                              type : "POST",
                              data:{type:type,subject:subject_id},
                              success : function(data){
                              if(type=="subject"){
                                  $("#care_subject_id").html(data);
                              }
                              else{
                                $("#care_class_id").append(data);
                              }
                              }
                             });
                        }
                    loadData();
                    $("#care_class_id").on("change",function(){
                        var cls =$("#care_class_id").val();
                        loadData("subject",cls);
                    })
                    });
                   
                </script>
<!-- /Container -->
            
    <?php include('footer.php')?>

<?php include('../../database_configuration/dbconfig.php')?>
<?php
if($_POST['type']=="")
{
 $class_sql="SELECT * FROM care_class";
 $class_query=mysqli_query($con,$class_sql);
 $str="";
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($class_query))
    {
        $str.="<option value='{$row['care_class_id']}'>{$row['care_class_number']}</option>";
    }
}
else if($_POST['type']=="subject")
{
$class_sql="SELECT * FROM care_subject WHERE care_class_id={$_POST['subject']} ";
$class_query=mysqli_query($con,$class_sql);
$str="";
     while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($class_query))
    {
        $str.="<option value='{$row['care_subject_id']}'>{$row['care_subject_name']}</option>";
    }    
}
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Any errors thrown in browser dev tools console (F12) or in back end? Have you checked all files are loading in the page?

Comment: no error found .. its works partilaly

Comment: Check version of all JS files that you use for your porject

Comment: yes check all version. I just copy one server to another server..old server link i already mentioned.its working fine